# Rails counter cache is not decrementing when associated items are deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have two ActiveRecord models `List` and `ListItem` as shown below.

```rb
class List < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items, -> { order(position: :asc) }, 
            class_name: "ListItem", 
            dependent: :destroy, 
            counter_cache: :items_count

  has_one :first_item, -> { order :id }, 
           class_name: "ListItem"

end
```

```rb
class ListItem < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :list, 
               counter_cache: :items_count, 
               touch: true
end
```

When I create a new `ListItem`, the counter cache field `items_count` is updating correctly. But when I destroy one, the count is not decrementing. Is there something wrong with this association or the counter cache implementation?

I checked a few already answered questions, like this one: [counter_cache not decrementing for has_many associations in ActiveReord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902995/counter-cache-not-decrementing-for-has-many-associations-in-activereord)
. Both the solutions suggested in the answers didn't work for me.

This is how I delete a list item in the controller:

```rb
def destroy
  list = current_user.lists.find_by(identifier: params[:list_identifier])
  if list
    list.items.find(params[:id]).destroy!
    head :no_content
  else
    render status: :not_found, json: { errors: "Invalid list" }
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you destroying or deleting list items? Can you see the SQL transaction logs after destroying a list item?

Comment: @SebastianPalma I am using the `destroy` method. I can see the SQL logs. If I try `List.last.items.count`, I get the correct count. But `List.last.items_count` gives me the count before destroying.

Comment: What happens if you call `List.last.reload` before `List.last.items_count`?

Comment: @dbugger I tried that. The count doesn't change even after `reload`.

Comment: What happens if you remove `counter_cache: :items_count` from the has_many?

Comment: The same. I started from there actually. I added that as per [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54071817/2139625).

Comment: Can you show the code where the `ListItem` is removed? Also your specific rails version would be helpful in this case

Comment: @engineersmnky Sure. I've updated the question with the controller method I use. I also tried `List.last.items.last.destroy!` from the rails console. That also didn't decrement the counter for `List.last`.